Why was this flag to remove an answer declined?
I flagged this answer for moderator attention because a) it's only a link and b) the link is dead and there's no wayback archive for it. Yet, the flag was declined:

Using standard flags helps us prioritize problems and resolve them faster. Please familiarize yourself with the list of standard flags.

Why?

What decline message did you get? Maybe it's because for something like this, an standard flag ("not an answer") would be preferred.

@yivi "Using standard flags helps us prioritize problems and resolve them faster. Please familiarize yourself with the list of standard flags". Years ago I might've flagged it as not an answer, however this appears to be an attempt at an answer, as bad as it seems

The link-only aspect of it does seem to be a bit of a red herring, that's not an attempt to answer any question. NAA. But still... splitting hairs really.

The decline message explains what's going on. The flag was declined because a standard flag ("not an answer") is the preferred way to deal with this.

@yivi The problem is in the past, if I flagged an answer like this as NAA, it also gets rejected because the moderator believes that it was in some small way, an attempt at an answer

Without more information, we cannot know what happened in the past. In this case, the mod rejected your flag because they clearly thought a standard flag was enough for this. The decline message was very clear, and should answer this particular question.

@yivi - In a case where a standard flag is more appropriate, does a moderator then go out and solve it themselves, because once you decline a flag that prevents the user who did flag the content from being able to flag the content again. Seems counterproductive to decline a custom flag because a standard flag exists, and others have suggested, when the standard flag is used it's decline because the custom flag should have been used.

@SecurityHound: "..  because once you decline a flag that prevents the user who did flag the content from being able to flag the content again." - As far as I know, there is no "flag-blocking" after the previous flag has been declined.

@Tsyvarev - If the flag is declined. The same user cannot raise a different flag on the same answer.

@j08691: Having a lot reputation (>20k) allows you to downvote and vote-to-delete an answer which is not completely crossed a NAA border but otherwise is quite a useless one. That way you will save a moderator's time and won't suffer from declined NAA flags.

@Tsyvarev You can downvote an answer (or a question, for that matter) with only 125 rep

@Starship: The key of 20k reputation is not just downvoting an answer but a voting to delete a negatively scored answer. An answer collecting 3 delete votes is deleted.

@Tsyvarev I know. I didn't say you could VTD an answer without 20k rep.

I can't speak for the mod who declined it, but I would not have declined your flag, or if I did, I would have deleted the post after declining.
That being said, what you flagged is clearly not an answer; it's just a link. This was something so obvious that you could have flagged it as Not An Answer and have it handled by normal users in the Low Quality Answers review, so a moderator may have declined it as not being something that required their attention. It's not a huge issue since moderators delete a lot of NAA flags anyway, and they do it quicker than the review, but it's something to keep in mind in the future.
The boilerplate decline "Using standard flags helps us prioritize problems and resolve them faster. Please familiarize yourself with the list of standard flags: see What is Flagging?" is generally used when users tell us about some problem that is usually handled by community, not moderators. An example is users flagging to get the question closed. It's because users who do not have privilege to vote to close, get the option to flag a question for closure. The flag will then push the question into the review queue instead of sending it to moderators. This decline reason is rarely used for anything else.

Always seems like a crap shoot when flagging as NAA. Been around here a long time and it feels like it's 50/50 at best and based on the moderator, not a hard rule. And the option for flagging this is low quality wasn't an option.

@j08691 I had a quick look at your flag history and it seems like a vast majority of your flags get accepted. But a word of advise: never use Very Low Quality. It's a terrible flag and mods hate it. It means exactly the same as NAA.

@Dharman - Doesn't the Very Low Quality make the contribution go into that queue to be reviewed by other users?

@SecurityHound It does, but it doesn't change the fact of how terrible that flag is. Just use NAA flag instead.

"if I did, I would have deleted the post after declining." Declining a flag requesting deletion of a post, but still deleting said post is rather paradoxical and should probably not be done except in edge cases. That's a great way to really confuse flaggers.

@TylerH Yeah, and I only really do it when I disagree with the flag message, but I agree that the post should be deleted nonetheless. To send the signal that the post should not have been deleted for the reason specified.

I feel like a "disputed" response would be better there, but IIRC that's not something mods can choose as an option when handling a flag. Would be nice if they could

@TylerH: I treat "disputed" flag as a signal "Given instance of the flag is controversial, but please continue to flag that way: we have no problems in handling such flags". While in the OP case the signal is different: "It is correct to flag such posts, but different kind of flags should be used instead". So I don't find a "disputed" status to be correct there.

I am confused by the messaging. If VLQ is a bad flag, why does it exist, how is it different from NAA from a UI perspective? I know what is displayed to a moderator unless there is context is difficult to judge but that’s not our fault when something isn’t flagged little to no other information is displayed in the moderator page?

@SecurityHound I am not sure why it exists, probably historical reasons. It's bad because it carries an automatic downvote and is marked helpful by an edit. To mods it's presented in the same way as NAA flag. In the review queue it's presented the same way too.

I notice that SO mods will decline flags when you were correct but you shouldn't have used In Need of Moderator Intervention, even the first time, whereas mods on other sites will mark it helpful and leave a note. Just curious, why?

@Dharman - So it’s disliked because of the automatic downvote?

@SecurityHound it exists because at some point it was considered a good idea, and it it is not removed because it is easier and cheaper to just leave it.

@Starship Pretty sure it has something to do with the sheer volume of flags handled in a day on Stack Overflow :)

@Gimby - If I had no read it myself from a moderator I would have not known VLQ should not be used.

@Tsyvarev That's a very "tomato, tomahto" viewpoint. In both cases the flagging of the content was a good action, but using the wrong flag type would certainly qualify for "the given instance of this flag is controversial".

@TylerH: You seem missed highlighted words in my comments: "continue to flag that way". This is a property of "helpful" and "disputed" flags, but this is not a property of "declined" flags. It is up to you to interpret these sorts of flags in different semantic, but comparison with "tomato, tomahto" doesn't look suitable in any case.

@Tsyvarev I didn't miss it, I just disagree. (And, as it happens, mods do also erroneously decline flags from time to time). The crux of what I suggested above was to improve the flexibility mods have in responding to/classifying flags.

@TylerH I know. I was more asking why do SO mods tend to always be on one side of that and everyone else on the other.
